# Dockerfile - nuxt: Permission denied

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

**I want to create a Dockerfile to build a webserver via NPM from a NuxtJS page.** Building with the Dockerfile works without problems, but as soon as I start the container via docker compose, I get an error. See my Dockerfile here:

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./data/package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY ./data .
EXPOSE 3000
ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S appuser && \
    adduser -u 1001 -S appuser -G appuser

RUN chown -R appuser:appuser /usr/src/app

USER appuser
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

thank you for any help.

**Here is my output:**

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/nuxtjs-docker-deployment# docker compose build --no-cache
    [+] Building 301.1s (12/12) FINISHED                                                                                                                                      docker:default
     => [web internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                            0.0s
     => => transferring dockerfile: 845B                                                                                                                                                0.0s
     => [web internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine                                                                                                               0.9s
     => [web internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                               0.0s
     => => transferring context: 68B                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
     => [web 1/7] FROM docker.io/library/node:18-alpine@sha256:b1a0356f7d6b86c958a06949d3db3f7fb27f95f627aa6157cb98bc65c801efa2                                                         0.0s
     => [web internal] load build context                                                                                                                                               5.2s
     => => transferring context: 1.59MB                                                                                                                                                 5.0s
     => CACHED [web 2/7] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                                                                           0.0s
     => [web 3/7] COPY ./data/package*.json ./                                                                                                                                          0.6s
     => [web 4/7] RUN npm install                                                                                                                                                      71.5s
     => [web 5/7] COPY ./data .                                                                                                                                                        32.3s 
     => [web 6/7] RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S appuser &&     adduser -u 1001 -S appuser -G appuser                                                                                          2.2s 
     => [web 7/7] RUN chown -R appuser:appuser /usr/src/app                                                                                                                           159.2s 
     => [web] exporting to image                                                                                                                                                       28.5s 
     => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                            28.5s 
     => => writing image sha256:18688212afa360bbeacd24b0b4ec9e064b56370276e2bd25cb9f0d42e7530783                                                                                        0.0s 
     => => naming to docker.io/library/nuxtjs-docker-deployment-web                                                                                                                     0.0s
    root@raspberrypi:/home/nuxtjs-docker-deployment# docker compose down -v && docker compose up -d
    [+] Running 2/2
     ✔ Container nuxtjs-docker-deployment-web-1  Removed                                                                                                                                0.0s 
     ✔ Network nuxtjs-docker-deployment_default  Removed                                                                                                                                0.4s 
    [+] Running 1/2
     ⠸ Network nuxtjs-docker-deployment_default  Created                                                                                                                                3.3s 
     ✔ Container nuxtjs-docker-deployment-web-1  Started                                                                                                                                3.1s 
    root@raspberrypi:/home/nuxtjs-docker-deployment# docker logs -f c27d9889469d
    
    > start
    > nuxt start
    
    sh: nuxt: Permission denied
    root@raspberrypi:/home/nuxtjs-docker-deployment#
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Odds are that this has nothing to do with docker-compose, for example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does your host system have a `node_modules` directory?  Do you have a `.dockerignore` file that excludes it from the image build?  It's possible the second `COPY` is overwriting the results of `RUN npm install`.

Comment: I don't think it's because of that. A .dockerignore already exists.